# "Meet" VS "Live up to"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference, idioms

I was wondering which choice is the correct one here and why?

> - The movie didn't ............ my expectations. *[connotation: the movie was not that satisfactory that I expected that to be.]*

a. meet 
b. live up to

I think they both are correct, but it is worth mentioning I have an intuition that "live up to" has a nuance that the expectations were high expectations while "meet" lacks such a nuance.

However, first of all, I'm not quite sure whether I'm correct in this case. Then, I have no clue if it is always like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both correct as you have identified.

There is an implication of dissapointmeant with both of these phrases so I wouldn't say it's necessarily correct that 'live up to' suggests higher expectations.
"I thought the movie was going to be amazing but it didn't meet my expectations" is a perfectly natural sentence and clearly suggests high expectations.

I would say that to me 'live up to' is a bit more lively and 'meet' is a bit flatter but this view may not be shared by everyone.

If you compare these definitions you will see that they have the exact same entry meaning these phrases are largely interchangeable: [Meet](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/meet+expectations#:%7E:text=video%20every%20day!-,meet%20(someone%27s)%20expectations,meet%20our%20expectations%20at%20all.) | [Live up to](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/live+up+to+expectations)